# Heroku with Lets Encrypt - can't rake the plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, heroku, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to set up Lets Encrypt SSL with my Rails 5 app.

I've finished the installation instructions for this gem: https://github.com/lgromanowski/letsencrypt-plugin/wiki/Installation-guide

And now I'm trying to do this step:

```
heroku run rake letsencrypt_plugin
```

I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
Acme::Client::Error::Malformed: Invalid character in DNS name
```

I don't know what this means or how to fix it. Has anyone sorted out Lets Encrypt SSL using this gem for heroku?

I've tried several other let's encrypt tutorials and am not getting anywhere. I want to try to sort this out using this gem if I can.

Comment: http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2016/01/12/lets-encrypt-with-a-rails-app-on-heroku/

Comment: That blog didn't work for me. I tried it before I tried the gem. Still looking to find a solution that I can get working

Comment: You don't need a gem to automatically get a certificate for your Heroku app: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management

Answer (score 0):

I've received that error before.  I had to change the domain name from https://example.com to example.com.  I believe that was because the '/' in the first url was considered an unacceptable character.  I can't help you with Ruby though, but maybe you can find something similar in your code.